# Almost sure convergence through subsequences

Tags: probability-theory, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

$\{X_i\}$'s are independent Poisson random variables with parameters $\lambda_i$ respectively satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n=\infty$. Define $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n$ then show that $$\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}\to 1 \quad \text{a.e}$$

My try :

This looks like a problem with the method of subsequences. Let us first prove convergence in probability.
$$P\left(|S_n-\mathbb{E}(S_n)|>\delta \mathbb{E}(S_n)\right)\le \frac{\text{var}(S_n)}{\delta^2(\mathbb{E}(S_n))^2}=\frac{1}{\delta^2\mathbb{E}(S_n)}\tag{$\ast$}$$
Since variance and mean of poisson are the same. Also the given series implies $\mathbb{E}(S_n)\to \infty$. So we have the probability convergence. Now define $n_k=\min \{n \mid \mathbb{E}(S_n)\geq k^2\}$ Now putting $T_k=S_{n_k}$ in $(\ast)$ we get that $$P\left(\left|\frac{T_k}{\mathbb{E}(T_k)}-1\right|>\delta\right)\leq \frac{1}{\delta^2k^2}$$ so summing over $k$, we get the lhs converges hence an easy application of Borel Cantelli Lemma 1 gives $\dfrac{T_k}{\mathbb{E}(T_k)}\to 1 \quad \text{a.e}$. Now I want to prove $$\frac{T_k}{\mathbb{E}(T_{k+1})}\le \frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}\le \frac{T_{k+1}}{\mathbb{E}(T_{k})}$$ for $n_k\le n<n_{k+1}$ which would give me my solution. Which is obvious. But to finish the proof I need $\dfrac{\mathbb{E}(T_k)}{\mathbb{E}(T_{k+1})}\to 1$. But I can't show this fact. How to do this? I tried to do it with $k^2$ replaced by $2^k$, but it doesn't help. Can someone help?

EDIT : I found [this](https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Spring2011/APM504/solutions/ps4-solutions.pdf) pdf which solves this problem in page 3. There they claim, that if we show $I_n/\mathbb{E}(I_n)\to 1 \; \text{a.e}$ then they also have $S_n/\mathbb{E}(S_n)\to 1\; \text{a.e}$. Why is that? I can see the convergence in probability for $S_n$ but nothing further. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Writing \text{var} doesn't yield proper spacing in things like $a\operatorname{var} b$, whereas \operatorname{var} does. (I haven't actually changed that but I edited for standard use of \mid and \tag{}. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You want to show
$$
\frac{\operatorname{E}(T_k)}{\operatorname{E}(T_{k+1})} \to 1 \text{ as } k \to \infty.
$$
You know
$$
k^2 \le \operatorname{E} (T_k) <(k+1)^2 \le \operatorname{E}(T_{k+1}) < (k+2)^2.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{k^2}{(k+2)^2} \le \frac{\operatorname{E}(T_k)}{\operatorname{E}(T_{k+1})} \le 1.
$$
You can probably go on from there.

Comment: I had that idea as well, but for all I know that $\operatorname{E}(T_{k+1})>(k+2)^2$ as well. I think that possibly it can be shown that for large $k$ this doesn't happen, so we can finish it, but I can't see it. That is why I actually posted it.